# Hide uploads folder name from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

As the topic says. I want to hide uploads folder name from url lets say I have url like this `http://mysite.com/t/uploads/n/myfile.htm` so I want to show it like `http://mysite.com/t/n/myfile.htm` but when I do that it doesn't loads CSS and images because of path so how do I do that so it loads CSS and images too. I'm using htaccess for this and using PHP `file_gets_content();` to show the file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using paths like `/path/to/css/file.css` or include the full URL `http://www.yoursite.com/path/to/css/file.css`

Comment: But It is database driven I mean I just create a folder and an html file and call css in html make its zip and upload to server then I want to do that instead of manually add the css link can I call css and images through php?

Comment: Your users upload HTML files that link to CSS and images you mean? Sorry if I'm finding it difficult to understand what you are actually doing.

Comment: I have created a directory where admin can upload content in zip format. So I wrote an script to unzip the file and upload it inside the uploads folder then when a user view it they have to write url like `http://mysite.com/t/n/myfile.htm` when I do that id doesn't load css I used php to serve files and I'm  sending all HTTP request to my request handling php script.

Comment: Try using Chrome or Firebug and look at what URL is being requested for the CSS file and compare that to what it should be.

Comment: I checked and there is no css because it is get html in css file instead of css it looks I have to updated something to my handler it also doesn't loads javascript etc.

Comment: You have HTML in your CSS file? That would be the problem then. And I don't know what you mean by updating your handler.

Comment: No, inside n folder I have a folder called css inside that there is css file so when I include uploads folder name in url it loads css other wise it don't

Comment: And sorry it loads page not found page I thought it was same html but no I just checked and it says 404 file not found.

Comment: Try adding a redirect in your .htaccess

Comment: How do I do that can you post code here?

Comment: Try Googling ".htaccess redirects`

Comment: doesn't works I did lots of search actually doing from last 2 days and nothing works because I just forward all http requests to my file handler

Comment: So then don't forward them to the file handler, forward them to the actual files.

Comment: yes you are right I just excluded images and js files and css files to be processed directly but the problem is I want to just upload mod_rewrite on them so when I write `http://mysite.com/t/n/myfile.css` they should be served directly via mod_rewrite from `http://mysite.com/t/uploads/n/myfile.css` that is what I want